# How can i access gtk.Entry() in my GUI script from my other script? Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I have #1 .py script which is a GTK GUI application and I have a second script which needs a string from the first script that can be gained by `gtk.Entry().get_text()`

The problem is that I dont know how to use that function/command outside of #1 script

Lets say #1 script is called test.py and inside there is:

```
def __init__(self):

    #some code

    #some code


    self.TextBox = gtk.Entry()

    self.TextBox .connect("key-press-event", self.keyEnter)

    #some code

    #some code

    #some code

def keyEnter(self, widget, ev):
    if ev.keyval == 65293 and not self.TextBox.get_text() == "":
    self.TextBox1.grab_focus()
    self.TextBox.set_editable(False)`
```

And #2 script is called test2.py and inside contains:

```
Meta = self.client.get_file_and_metadata(#here it needs to go self.Textbox.get_text())
```

Comment: Sorry for messy code alignment... this is my first post :D

Comment: Are the scripts run in separate processes or are they two modules in a single process? If they are separate processes, you will need to use some inter-process communication to get the text out of the first script.

Comment: Yes the scripts are run in separate processes. I found my self a walk through option and got what i wanted

Comment: If you resolved the question, please post an answer, so that it remains for future visitors. It's not obvious what you mean by *walk through option*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't access the `gtk.Entry()` from other script I wrote since it is run as a separate process (i don't have that knowledge to manipulate processes yet) i did this:

```
def keyEnter(self, widget, ev):
    if ev.keyval == 65293 and not self.TextBox.get_text() == "":
    self.TextBox1.grab_focus()
    self.TextBox.set_editable(False)
    file = open('file.txt', 'w+')
    file.write(self.TextBox.get_text())
    file.close()
```

i changed

```
Meta = self.client.get_file_and_metadata(#here it needs to go self.Textbox.get_text())
```

that was supposed to download the file with the name written in `self.Textbox`

i changed it to

```
Meta = self.client.get_file_and_metadata(getpass.getuser())
```

and finally the string from `self.Textbox` i got through uploading

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as chat:
    data=chat.read().splitlines(True) #split lines in the list
d = str(data[:1]) #take only first line from the list
dat=str(d).strip("[]") #remove the brackets "[]" that remained when string was extracted from the list
with open("file.txt", "w") as chat1:
    chat1.writelines(data[1:]) # writes all except the first line
chat.close()
chat1.close()
self.f = open('file.txt', 'rb')
self.response = self.client.put_file(str(dat[:-2]), self.f)  #str(dat[:-2]) -> i wanted to remove the newline char "\n"
```

I dont know if anyone will find this helpful but this solved the problem at my side :))